# 2 player zero-sum-game rock paper scissors expected loss

Tags: linear-programming, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

For the Rock-Paper-Scissors game, I am trying to determine the expected loss for P1.

The following matrix displays how much P1 has lost: 
A: 
| 0 1 -1 | 
| -1 0 1 | 
| 1 -1 0 |

I am trying to find the expected loss for P1 when P1 uses mixed strategy x = (x1, x2, x3) and P2 uses mixed strategy y (y1, y2, y3)

I am not sure how to do this?

EDIT:
My attempt is thinking that if I should always have a 1/3 chance of winning, right?

Comment: There are only $9$ things that can happen.  Figure out their probabilities and add up the expected gains and losses.

Comment: the solution proposed by saulspatz can be written elegantly in terms of $A$, $x$ and $y$

Comment: I will attempt this, and post an answer. Thank you for the feed back.

Comment: It's true that you can always break even by playing $x = (1/3,1/3,1/3)$. But you can possibly do better, depending on P2's strategy. If P2 always plays rock, then you can always play paper and win every time.

Comment: @Théophile thank you for the feedback. I know this is dumb question but I am trying so hard to understand it

Comment: You can take the payoffs from the matrix one by one and add them up, scaled by the corresponding probabilities. The probability that both players play rock is $x_1y_1$, so the loss for that is $0x_1y_1 = 0$. The probability that P1 plays rock but P2 plays paper is $x_1y_2$, with a corresponding loss of $1x_1y_2 = x_1y_2$. Do the same for the remaining elements and add everything together. You will end up with an expression involving all the $x_i$ and $y_j$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected payoff for $P1$ when he plays the mixed strategy $x$ and his opponent plays the mixed strategy $y$ is $x A y^\top$.